# Play audio through upper (phone call) speaker

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, media-player, audiotoolbox

I'm trying to get audio in my app to play through the upper speaker on the iPhone, the one you press to your ear during a phone call.  I know it's possible, because I've played a game from the App Store ("The Heist" by "tap tap tap") that simulates phone calls and does exactly that.

I've done a lot of research online, but I'm having a surprisingly hard time finding ANYONE who has even discussed the possibility.  The overwhelming majority of posts seem to be about the handsfree speaker vs plugged-in earphones, (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128455/switching-between-headphone-speaker-on-iphone?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931799/redirecting-audio-output-to-phone-speaker-and-mic-input-to-headphones?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963011/in-ios-5-how-to-use-audiosession-to-make-sure-audio-is-played-through-speaker-a?rq=1)), rather than the upper "phone call" speaker vs the handsfree speaker.  (Part of that problem might be not having a good name for it: "phone speaker" often means the handsfree speaker at the bottom of the device, etc, so it's hard to do a really well-targeted search).  I've looked into Apple's `Audio Session Category Route Overrides`, but those again seem to (correct me if I'm wrong) deal only with the handsfree speaker at the bottom, not the speaker at the top of the phone.

I have found ONE post that seems to be about this: [link](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/107557-sound-play-through-upper-speaker.html).  It even provides a bunch of code, so I thought I was home free, but now I can't seem to get the code to work.  For simplicity I just copied the `DisableSpeakerPhone` method (which if I understand it correctly should be the one to re-route audio to the upper speaker) into my `viewDidLoad` to see if it would work, but the first "assert" line fails, and the audio continues to play out the bottom.  (I also imported the AudioToolbox Framework, as suggested in the comment, so that isn't the problem.)

Here is the main block of code I'm working with (this is what I copied into my `viewDidLoad` to test), although there are a few more methods in the article I linked to:

```
void DisableSpeakerPhone () {
    UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
    CFStringRef currentRoute = NULL;
    OSStatus result = noErr;

    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &dataSize, &currentRoute);

    // Set the category to use the speakers and microphone.
    UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
    result = AudioSessionSetProperty (
                                      kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                                      sizeof (sessionCategory),
                                      &sessionCategory
                                      );
    assert(result == kAudioSessionNoError);

    Float64 sampleRate = 44100.0;
    dataSize = sizeof(sampleRate);
    result = AudioSessionSetProperty (
                                      kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareSampleRate,
                                      dataSize,
                                      &sampleRate
                                      );
    assert(result == kAudioSessionNoError);

    // Default to speakerphone if a headset isn't plugged in.
    // Overriding the output audio route

    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None; 
    dataSize = sizeof(audioRouteOverride);
    AudioSessionSetProperty(
                            kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                            dataSize,
                            &audioRouteOverride);

    assert(result == kAudioSessionNoError);

    AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
}
```

**So my question is this:** can anyone either A) help me figure out why that code doesn't work, or B) offer a better suggestion for being able to press a button and route the audio up to the upper speaker?

PS  I am getting more and more familiar with iOS programming, but this is my first foray into the world of AudioSessions and such, so details and code samples are much appreciated!  Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE:**

From the suggestion of "He Was" (below) I've removed the code quoted above and replaced it with:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error:nil];
```

at the beginning of `viewDidLoad`.  It still isn't working, though, (by which I mean the audio is still coming out of the speaker at the bottom of the phone instead of the receiver at the top).  Apparently the default behavior should be for `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` to send audio out of the receiver on its own, so something is still wrong.

More specifically what I'm doing with this code is playing audio through the iPod Music Player (initialized right after the AVAudioSession lines above in `viewDidLoad`, for what it's worth):

```
_musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
```

and the media for that iPod Music Player is chosen through an `MPMediaPickerController`:

```
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection {
    if (mediaItemCollection) {
        [_musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection: mediaItemCollection];
        [_musicPlayer play];
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This all seems fairly straightforward to me, I've got no errors or warnings, and I know that the Media Picker and Music Player are working correctly because the correct songs start playing, it's just out of the wrong speaker. Could there be a "play media using this AudioSession" method or something?  Or is there a way to check what audio session category is currently active, to confirm that nothing could have switched it back or something?  Is there a way to emphatically tell the code to USE the receiver, rather than relying on the default to do so?  I feel like I'm on the one-yard line, I just need to cross that final bit...

**EDIT:** I just thought of a theory, wherein it's something about the iPod Music Player that doesn't want to play out of the receiver.  My reasoning: it is possible to set a song to start playing through the official iPod app and then seamlessly adjust it (pause, skip, etc) through the app I'm developing.  The continuous playback from one app to the next made me think that maybe the iPod Music Player has its own audio route settings, or maybe it doesn't stop to check the settings in the new app?  Does anyone who knows what they're talking about think it could it be something like that?

Comment: Tried just nuking the asserts and seeing what happens?

Comment: Comment them all out, and it's like there's no code there at all: audio goes through the bottom speaker.  I imagine that's because of the same problem that's causing the asserts to fail, I'm just not experienced enough to know what that might be.

Comment: I'm not either... Good luck!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159695/call-receive-to-receiver-to-play-sound

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to initialise your audio session first.

Using the C API

```
  AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

In iOS6 you can use AVAudioSession methods instead (you will need to import the AVFoundation framework to use `AVAudioSession`):

Initialization using AVAudioSession

```
 self.audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
```

Setting the audioSession category  using AVAudioSession

```
 [self.audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                       error:nil];
```

For further research, if you want better search terms, here are the full names of the constants for the speakers:

```
const CFStringRef kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BuiltInReceiver;
const CFStringRef kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BuiltInSpeaker;
```

see apple's docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)

But the real mystery is why you are having any trouble routing to the receiver. It's the default behaviour for the playAndRecord category. Apple's documentation of `kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None`:

"Specifies, for the kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord category, that output audio should go to the receiver. **This is the default output audio route for this category.**"

**update**

In your updated question you reveal that you are using the `MPMusicPlayerController` class. This class invokes the global music player (the same player used in the Music app). This music player is separate from your app, and so doesn't share the same audio session as your app's audioSession. Any properties you set on your app's audioSession will be ignored by the MPMusicPlayerController.

If you want control over your app's audio behaviour, you need to use an audio framework internal to your app. This would be `AVAudioRecorder` / `AVAudioPlayer` or Core Audio (Audio Queues, Audio Units or OpenAL). Whichever method you use, the audio session can be controlled either via `AVAudioSession` properties or via the Core Audio API. Core Audio gives you more fine-grained control, but with each new release of iOS more of it is ported over to AVFoundation, so start with that.

Also remember that the audio session provides a way for you to describe the intended behaviour of your app's audio in relation to the total iOS environment, but it will not hand you total control. Apple takes care to ensure that the user's expectations of their device's audio behaviour remain consistent between apps, and when one app needs to interrupt another's audio stream.

**update 2**

In your edit you allude to the possibility of audio sessions checking other app's audio session settings. That does not happen<sup>1</sup>. The idea is that each app sets it's preferences for it's own audio behaviour using it's self-contained audio session. The *operating system* arbitrates between conflicting audio requirements when more than one app competes for an unshareable resource, such as the internal microphone or one of the speakers, and will usually decide in favour of that behaviour which is most likely to meet the user's expectations of the device as a whole.

The MPMusicPlayerController class is slightly unusual in that it gives you the ability for one app to have some degree of control over another. In this case, your app is not playing the audio, it is sending a request to the Music Player to play audio on your behalf. Your control is limited by the extent of the MPMusicPlayerController API. For more control, your app will have to provide it's own implementation of audio playback.

In your comment you wonder:

> Could there be a way to pull an MPMediaItem from the MPMusicPlayerController and then play them through the app-specific audio session, or anything like that?

That's a (big) subject for a new question. Here is a good starting read (from Chris Adamson's blog) [From iPod Library to PCM Samples in Far Fewer Steps Than Were Previously Necessary](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/) - it's the sequel to [From iphone media library to pcm samples in dozens of confounding and potentially lossy steps](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/07/19/from-iphone-media-library-to-pcm-samples-in-dozens-of-confounding-potentially-lossy-steps/) - that should give you a sense to the complexity you will face. This *may* have got easier since iOS6 but I wouldn't be so sure!

---

<sup>1</sup> there is an `otherAudioPlaying` read-only BOOL property in ios6, but that's about it

Comment: Thank you! I've just looked into `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` and it might be exactly what I'm looking for. However, I've added the lines `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil]; [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];` in place of the code I posted to `viewDidLoad`, and I'm not getting any errors but it still plays through the speaker.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Should those lines not go in `viewDidLoad`, or do I need to do anything with my `[self.musicPlayer play];` lines or anything?

Comment: @AlexanderWinn - yes they should go in viewDidLoad. You need to initialize the audioSession before setting any properties on it. `[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]` achieves that. As regards `[self.musicPlayer play]` you didn't post that code in your original question. Perhaps you should update the question with more code context, as the code you have already posted should just work.

Comment: Updated.  Does anything in there look like it might be the issue?  And thank you again for your help so far!

Comment: @AlexanderWinn - see my updated reply. If you want to dig deeper into Core Audio I strongly recommend the "Learning Core Audio" book by Chris Adamson and Kevin Avila.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  So if I'm understanding you correctly, `AVAudioSession` or CoreAudio are the best ways to control the audio that is specific to my app, but since I'm using `MPMusicPlayerController` and the global music player, the audio session is separate and therefore there is no way to redirect the output to the receiver.  Is that right?  Could there be a way to pull an MPMediaItem from the `MPMusicPlayerController` and then play them through the app-specific audio session, or anything like that?

Comment: @AlexanderWinn - In answer to the first question: yes that is correct.

Comment: @AlexanderWinn - in answer to your second Q, see my second update!

Comment: MR: @foundry i think you are able to answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026578/play-audio-through-upper-phone-call-speaker

Comment: @KishoreKumar - i've posted an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38610471/1375695)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159695/call-receive-to-receiver-to-play-sound Plz give me the ans

Answer (score 28):

Was struggling with this for a while too. Maybe this would help someone later.You can also use the newer methods of overriding ports. Many of the methods in your sample code are actually deprecated.

So if you have your AudioSession sharedInstance by getting,

```
NSError *error = nil;
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
[session setActive: YES error:nil];
```

The session category has to be AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
You can get the current output by checking this value.

```
AVAudioSessionPortDescription *routePort = session.currentRoute.outputs.firstObject;
NSString *portType = routePort.portType;
```

And now depending on the port you want to send it to, simply toggle the output using

```
if ([portType isEqualToString:@"Receiver"]) {
       [session  overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
} else {
       [session  overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
}
```

This should be a quick way to toggle the outputs to the speaker phone and receiver.

Comment: Works great! I just had to change the session category and override the output audio port, easy! thanks

Comment: Tried this solution iOS 8. This works. Just have         [session  overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:nil];
 if you don't want it to toggle and just play the sound in the ear piece.

Comment: can you please have a look this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424446/avaudiosession-playing-audio-through-earpiece-speaker

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0 Code**

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {       
let routePort: AVAudioSessionPortDescription? = obsession. current Route. outputs. first
let portType: String? = routePort?.portType
if (portType == "Receiver") {
    try? audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
   }
   else {
        try? audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
   }
```

Comment: can you please have a look this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424446/avaudiosession-playing-audio-through-earpiece-speaker

Answer (score 0):

**swift 5.0**

```
func activateProximitySensor(isOn: Bool) {
    let device = UIDevice.current
    device.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = isOn
    if isOn {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(proximityStateDidChange), name: UIDevice.proximityStateDidChangeNotification, object: device)
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do{
            try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord)
            try session.setActive(true)
            try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
        } catch {
            print ("\(#file) - \(#function) error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIDevice.proximityStateDidChangeNotification, object: device)
    }
}

@objc func proximityStateDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let device = notification.object as? UIDevice {
        print(device)
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do{
            let routePort: AVAudioSessionPortDescription? = session.currentRoute.outputs.first
            let portType = routePort?.portType
            if let type = portType, type.rawValue == "Receiver" {
                try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
            } else {
                try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.none)
            }
        } catch {
            print ("\(#file) - \(#function) error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```