# How to play AVSpeechSynthesizer through call receiver speaker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avspeechsynthesizer

I like to play audio through the call receiver speaker ,currently i am using this for play some text as a audio .

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:_strTextCheck];
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *syn = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    [syn speakUtterance:utterance];
```

I got but this is not for AVSpeechSynthesizer:

```
[AVAudioSession  overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
```

Correctly its working on a normal speaker but i want to make to play through call receiver speaker ,is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behaviour is to play through the call receiver. So if you unset the override - or don't set it in the first place - you should get the behaviour you are after:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] 
     overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone
                       error:nil];
```

Here is a full example. You need to also set the audioSession category.

```
- (void)playVoice {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] 
             setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                  error:nil];

    //try one or the other but not both...

    //[self playVoiceOnSpeaker:@"test test test"];

    [self playVoiceOnReceiver:@"test test test"];

}

-(void)playVoiceOnSpeaker:(NSString*)str
{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]  
         overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
                           error:nil];
    [self playVoiceByComputer:str];
}

-(void)playVoiceOnReceiver:(NSString*)str
{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
         overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone
                           error:nil];
    [self playVoiceByComputer:str];
}

-(void)playVoiceByComputer:(NSString*)str
{
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = 
          [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:str];
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *syn = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    [syn speakUtterance:utterance];
}
```

Comment: but still its running on speaker bro http://paste.ofcode.org/uEi8M5FjcGhB97NurcEEsM

Comment: through receiver speaker its not running

Comment: @KishoreKumar - see my update - you need to check your audioSession category is correct

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: [.defaultToSpeaker])
```