# How to play audio from earpiece in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudiosession

I want to play audio from earpiece . I tried the solution provided in this : [Play Audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026578/play-audio-through-upper-phone-call-speaker) but it is not working. I also tried

```
 NSError *error = nil;
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
        [session setActive: YES error:nil];

        AVAudioSessionPortDescription *routePort = session.currentRoute.outputs.firstObject;

        [session  overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

I play audio from earpiece by writing these lines in my ViewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
NSError *error = nil;
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    [session setActive: YES error:nil];
    [session  overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
```